# What's wrong with my getNumber() function?

Tags: c++, function, validation

I'm making a program for class, if you run it and enter positive numbers, the purpose of the assignment is clear. However, it appears my `int getNumber();` function isn't working correctly. The purpose of the function is to collect a single positive number and return it. 
Here's the code:

```
    int getNumber()
{
    int number;
    cin >> number;
    if (number < 0)
    {
        cout << endl; "Number cannot be negative: Please enter a nonnegative value: ";
        cin >> number;
    }
    else 
        return (number); 
}
```

If you need the rest of the program let me know. I call it as `i = getNumber(); movies = new int[i];`

EDIT: Sorry, I forgot to mention that the problem was it wouldn't print out the cout line, but would end the line correctly. Immediately after posting it I remembered that if-else was a condition clause and not a loop and switched it but still had the same problem. I didn't realize that it would still accept a negative number because I always ended the program once it failed to print the line "Number cannot be negative..." I put a `;` instead of `<<` after `endl`, but thanks for solving a problem I didn't know I would have. And sorry for not actually saying the problem the first time around.

Comment: Besides indentation, I assume?

Comment: Learn to think like a programmer and don't use terms like "isn't working correctly". What does that tell us about what the problem might be? It could fail to compile (my assumption), or give incorrect results, in which case you should describe those results.

Comment: In addition to only returning from your else clause, `number` can still remain negative if they input a negative number the second time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only one branch of your `if` condition returns a value.  If the first number entered is negative, the function doesn't return anything.

Your compiler should have warned about this.

You probably want to replace your `if` with a `while` loop which executes repeatedly until an acceptable number is entered:

```
int getNumber()
{
    int number;
    cin >> number;
    while (number < 0)
    {
        cout << endl; "Number cannot be negative: Please enter a nonnegative value: ";
        cin >> number;
    }
    return number; 
}
```

Comment: You could also replace it with a do-while loop to avoid code duplication ... and add error checking to the input.  But as this is a homework assignment, that should be left for him to figure out :)

Answer (score 1):

Your code only returns a value when the number is not negative. I'm assuming this is a compiler error.

Also, what happens if it's a negative number but the user enters a second negative number. You need something more like this:

```
int getNumber()
{
    int number;

    cin >> number;
    while (number < 0)
    {
        cout << endl; "Number cannot be negative: Please enter a nonnegative value: ";
        cin >> number;
    }
    return number;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    int getNumber()
{
    int number;
    cin >> number;
    while(number<0) // A while loop will allow you to continually input numbers if the value is negative
    {
        cout << endl; "Number cannot be negative: Please enter a nonnegative value: ";
        cin >> number;
    }

        return number; // you don't need parenthesis before and after number
}
```